# Allow trailing slash for Symfony2 route without params?

Tags: symfony, yaml

```
acme_admin_dashboard:
    pattern:  /{_locale}/admin
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Admin:dashboard }
```

I want this route to be accessible at `/en/admin` and `/en/admin/`. How would I achieve this?

Comment: See this [cookbook entry](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I like @Kuchengeschmack's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11078348/593957) because it doesn't trigger external redirects.

Here's a yaml version:

```
acme_admin_dashboard:
    pattern:  /{_locale}/admin{trailingSlash}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Admin:dashboard, trailingSlash : "/" }
    requirements: { trailingSlash : "[/]{0,1}" }
```

Comment: on a sidenode this is especially useful when using FOSRestBundle, because then your REST interface isn't returning external redirects.

Comment: you can simply use `\?` as requirements and you can omit default definition

Comment: I find this solution very heavy for the little things it makes...
Writing the rules like ine Damien's answer is better, and it's working well.

Answer (score 20):

Just type :

```
/**
* @Route("/route/of/some/page/")
*/
```

so

```
www.example.com/route/of/some/page
```

and

```
www.example.com/route/of/some/page/
```

are accepted...

Comment: but then all links are by default with a trailing slash.. which seems a bit rough

Comment: Oh hell you dont want to do this! It does 301 - Moved Permanently and thus DOESN'T RESEND POST parameters! ( https://maltronic.io/2015/08/09/adding-removing-trailing-slashes-from-urls/ )

Answer (score 13):

I found a solution to add a trailing slash to a route.

means both link are working   `www.example.com/route/of/some/page` and `www.example.com/route/of/some/page/`. You can do is this way:

if you route looks like

```
/**
 * @Route("/route/of/some/page")
 */
public function pageAction() {
```

change ist to

```
/**
 * @Route("/route/of/some/page{trailingSlash}", requirements={"trailingSlash" = "[/]{0,1}"}, defaults={"trailingSlash" = "/"})
 */
public function pageAction() {
```

Comment: Totally pointless, just use a trailing slash as in the accepted  answer.

Comment: I like the creative thought behind it!

Comment: This is not pointless. It works great for preflight OPTIONS requests, which are not allowed to have redirects.

Comment: Nice! As @r0ber7 mentioned, it removes the 301 redirect :) Will make your code messy if you end up doing this for all your routes - but I love the idea!

Comment: This is really useful if your routes are consumed by clients that cannot follow 301 redirects. This way you get a 200 response on both with and without a trailing slash.

Answer (score 10):

You could also simply use rewrite rule in the .htaccess file:

Say you have defined a route like so:

```
news:
  url:   /news
  param: { module: news, action: index }
```

This will be matched by http://something.something/news, but not by http://something.something/news/
You might add an additional route with a trailing slash, but you could also simply use this rewrite rule in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

[http://symfony-blog.driebit.nl/2010/07/url-routes-with-or-without-a-trailing-slash/](http://web.archive.org/web/20120121055039/http://symfony-blog.driebit.nl/2010/07/url-routes-with-or-without-a-trailing-slash)

Comment: I like this solution. Restricting the problem to the server layer seems appropriate since no application logic is required at all.

Comment: ^ But it *is* something that is required to make the application work as expected..

Answer (score 6):

I hacked the following line into front controller (app.php / app_dev.php)

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = preg_replace('|/$|', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
```

before `$request = Request::createFromGlobals()`

Comment: It´s kind of hacky but I like it.

Comment: Like it! I think Symfony team should integrate this solution into code base.

Answer (score 5):

**Route:**

```
 remove_trailing_slash:
        path: /{url}
        defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Redirecting:removeTrailingSlash }
        requirements:
            url: .*/$
        methods: [GET]
```

**Controller:**

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/RedirectingController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class RedirectingController extends Controller
{
    public function removeTrailingSlashAction(Request $request)
    {
        $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
        $requestUri = $request->getRequestUri();

        $url = str_replace($pathInfo, rtrim($pathInfo, ' /'), $requestUri);

        return $this->redirect($url, 301);
    }
}
```

Read more: http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html

Answer (score 1):

For new SF versions:

By default, the Symfony Routing component requires that the parameters match the following regex path: `[^/]+`. This means that all characters are allowed except `/`.

You must explicitly allow `/` to be part of your parameter by specifying a more permissive regex path.

**YAML:**

```
_hello:
    path:     /hello/{username}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Demo:hello }
    requirements:
        username: .+
```

**XML:**

```
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <route id="_hello" path="/hello/{username}">
        <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Demo:hello</default>
        <requirement key="username">.+</requirement>
    </route>
</routes>
```

**PHP:**

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

$collection = new RouteCollection();
$collection->add('_hello', new Route('/hello/{username}', array(
    '_controller' => 'AppBundle:Demo:hello',
), array(
    'username' => '.+',
)));

return $collection;
```

**Annotations:**

```
/**
 * @Route("/hello/{username}", name="_hello", requirements={"username"=".+"})
 */
public function helloAction($username)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: But when request is /hello/john/ then $username would be john/ and will need extra parsing.