# Symfony2 router incosistency with trailing slash

Tags: php, url, symfony, redirect, symfony-2.4

I have a very simple bundle controller

```
<?php

namespace Mnab\ContactBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($anything)
    {
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response(__CLASS__ .' '.$anything);
        //return $this->render('MnabContactBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $anything));
    }
}
```

I have roter config in YML files

**CASE 1**: My routing for this controller looks like:

```
mnab_contact_homepage:
    pattern:  contact/{anything}
    defaults: { _controller: MnabContactBundle:Default:index, anything: null }
    requirements:
      anything: .*
```

In this case application accepts for this controller the following urls:

> /contact /contact/ /contact/bla /contact/bla/bla/blabla

and so on

**CASE 2** My routing for this controller looks like:

```
mnab_contact_homepage:
    pattern:  contact/
    defaults: { _controller: MnabContactBundle:Default:index, anything: null }
    requirements:
      anything: .*
```

In this case application accepts only

> /contact/

and

if there is url:

> /contact -> it makes redirection (dont' know what type 301 or 302) to /contact/ url

**CASE 3** My routing for this controller looks like:

```
mnab_contact_homepage:
    pattern:  contact
    defaults: { _controller: MnabContactBundle:Default:index, anything: null }
    requirements:
      anything: .*
```

In this case application accepts only

> /contact

**Expected results**

In case 3 everything is as I expect but case 1 and 2 works not as I expect

**Questions**

1. Why in *case 1* application accepts also /contact url ? I have clearly expect /contact/ url not contact/
2. Why in *case 2* applications accepts also /contact url making redirection for it to /contact/
3. Why behaviour is different in *case 1* and *case 2*
4. Is it possible to change this behaviour - for example not accept at all /contact in my case ? (In fact I don't mind because I want some urls with trailing slash but in *case 1* I'll have to do redirection for version without trailing slash)
5. Does Symfony do such "tricks" for all urls (also with extension as for example I define it works for /test.html and Symfony makes it work also for /test.html/ ) or only for those without extension?
6. Where can I read a bit more about such cases?

Comment: Take a look this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14894077/453348)

Comment: I saw this today and saw this trick but it's for me rather "hack" to make it work but still I don't understand why in 2 cases Symfony behaves different

Comment: Behaves different because the paterns are differents, I would like that sf2 support regex inside the pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why in case 1 application accepts also /contact url? I have clearly
>   expect /contact/ url not contact/

`/contact` means that you are leaving out the `anything` parameter which will be in this case `null`.

`/contact/` means that you are NOT leaving out the `anything` parameter. In this case `NotFoundHttpException` should be thrown, because you haven't provided any value for `anything` parameter.

> Why in case 2 applications accepts also /contact url making
>   redirection for it to /contact/

It is behaviour of [Symfony2 routing component](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/Routing), there can't be really told more about it.

> Why behaviour is different in case 1 and case 2

Because in case 1 there is a parameter in the route. The parameter has although a default value. In case 2 there is no parameter in the route.

> Is it possible to change this behaviour - for example not accept at
>   all /contact in my case

Yes, for example make the `anything` parameter to be mandatory, not optional.

> Does Symfony do such "tricks" for all urls (also with extension as for
>   example I define it works for /test.html and Symfony makes it work
>   also for /test.html/ ) or only for those without extension

Behaviour of the routing component is consistent, it does not matter if you use `test` or `test.html`.

> Where can I read a bit more about such cases?

There won't be many sources regarding this, but you can always check out source code of the [routing component](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/Routing).

However, documentation to routing component can be found here [Routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/index.html).

Comment: So to clarify, each time when I have controller with similar route contact/{anything} and anything is optional, Symfony2 treats that slash is also optional because it's treated as parameters separator and when there is no second parameter in url symfony2 think that slash will be unnecessary in that case. Does it work this way?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Yes, correct. For your URL "/contact/{anything}" applies: if there is "/contact" = no parameter and default value is assigned to the parameter, if there is "/contact/" - parameter value is expected otherwise an exception is thrown.