# Trailing slash for route default?

Tags: symfony, routes, yaml

I have the following route:

```
reviews:
    pattern: /reviews/{uid}{trailingSlash}
    defaults: { _controller: unrealsp.cms.controller:handle_review, uid: "index", trailingSlash : "/" }
    requirements: { trailingSlash : "[/]{0,1}" }
```

I made this work with trailing slashes using [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14894077/2275217).

The route will recognize the "/reviews" URL and refer to the **index** *uid*, displaying an index of available reviews (rather than single reviews it would call with any other *uid*). However, it will not recognize "/reviews/" as index, saying there is no such route. How do I go about changing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changig it to:

```
pattern: /reviews/
```

`{uid}` makes the parameter required by the router, so if you want /reviews/ to be valid, you have to remove it from route definition. This way you would just add in the controller:

```
$uid = $request->get('uid','index');
```

Another solution is:

```
reviews:
    pattern: /reviews/{uid}
    defaults: { _controller: unrealsp.cms.controller:handle_review }
    requirements: { uid: "\d+" }

reviews_index:
    pattern: /reviews/
    defaults: { _controller: unrealsp.cms.controller:handle_review }
```

Comment: That way, I cannot access any reviews which aren't the review index page.

Comment: remove uid: "index", trailingSlash : "/" }
    requirements: { trailingSlash : "[/]{0,1}" }

why? in controller you should just do $uid = $request->get('uid','index');

Comment: That makes no sense in my eyes. Then all I'm left with is a /reviews/ route iwth no parameters whatsoever. How is it supposed to know what is 'index' and what is 'uid' when neither are defined in the route?

Comment: "It"(the router) is not, it's the controller that will handle it.
The only difference is that you will move from /reviews/XXX to /reviews/?id=XXX

Another thing would be to add 2'd route, I updated my answer