# Symfony routing : path() method don't write default param value

Tags: php, symfony, routes, twig

I have two routes :

```
// routing.yml
foo_list:
    path: /foo
    defaults: { _controller:MyBundle:Foo:index }

foo_view:
    path: /foo/{id}
    defaults:
        _controller: AlfnooBundle:Exploitant:view
        id : 1
    requirements:
        id: \d*
```

The first one is for a page which lists all the foos, the second one is the page which display a detailed view of foo n. {id}. In my Twig view, I generate the link to `foo_view` like this :

```
{{path('foo_view', {'id': foo.id})}}
```

It's OK if `id` is not `1` (the default value) : `/foo/12345`. But if `id` is `1`, the `path()` method generates a wrong url, it ommits the `id` param, and the generated route is : `/foo`. Which is not `foo_view`, but `foo_list`. If I change the default value, the issue is for the default value.

```
{{path('foo_view', {'id': 1})}}     => /foo     => BAD ! I want /foo/1
{{path('foo_view', {'id': 123})}}   => /foo/123 => GOOD
```

So how can I force Twig `path()` methods to always add the param value, even if it is the default value ? I want to keep disctincts urls for :

```
/foo            => foo_list
/foo/           => foo_view with id=1
/foo/12345      => foo_view with id=12345
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why do not remove this default value for id ?

Comment: @DOZ Because I want distincts actions for for url `/foo`and url `/foo/`, and keep `/foo/`without id valid (with 1 by default).

Comment: Let the requirement, and remove the default ...

Comment: as @Alsatian says :)

Comment: @Alsatian And what about my default value ? I managed it in the controller ? It seems not elegant to me :)

Comment: but from what I understand the default value is not used, or the URL has an id or it did not...

Comment: If you always send the value, you don't use a default value ...

Comment: @Alsatian I have to keep compatibility with site previous version urls, that's why I need both with and without id. But I will suppress the default value in routing.yml and check it in my controller. Thks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this, at least not in this way. Symfony's router does not generate paths with trailing slashes.

The path generated by `path('foo_view')` will always be `/foo` and will never be `/foo/` and since you've specified a default for `id` the path will never be `/foo/1` either, as you've seen.

There [is a way to coerce trailing slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792544/allow-trailing-slash-for-symfony2-route-without-params) but it's a but clumsy if you ask me.